# Find the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ by just using the common rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ by just using the common rules of differentiation, such as *sum*, *scalar multiplication*, *product*, *quotient rule*, the *chain rule* and the *inverse function*.

Now, I know that the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, and I have seen around proofs using some weirds techniques that I have not seen directly the in class, but I do not want to use those.

If I try to compute the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$ by applying the _inverse function rule_$$(f^{-1})' = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1})}$$ I come with something different than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$:

$$\frac{1}{\sin'(\arcsin(x))} = \frac{1}{\cos(\arcsin(x))}$$

I am probably forgetting something...

**Please do not show me [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Arcsine_Function) again**.

Comment: Remember that $\cos^2 \theta = 1 - \sin^2\theta$.

Comment: Quite. The only fiddily bit is taking the square-root (how do you know $\cos$ is positive?) but this is taken care of, by the domain of $\arcsin$, on which $\cos$ is positive.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the codomain of arcsin is what helps you out.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** 
$$
\arcsin x\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]
$$
interval on which $\cos(x)\ge 0$. Use the formula $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ with $\theta = \arcsin x$.